# The WebDemo project is not in the Flinks.sln solution anymore, how do you debug it?

Tags: visual-studio

The WebDemo project for Flinks connect does not appear anymore in the list of projects in the Flinks.sln solution. How do you debug Flinks Connect?

Answer (score 0):

Flinks Connect now has its own solution (FlinksConnect.sln). Why? Prevent from loading unnecessary files when working with the API (for those using resharper, it can take forever to load the solution because of the node modules) and prevent from restoring unnecessary nuget packages when restoring all the packages for the solution (saves time in the CI which is already long).

Ways to debug : if you only need to debug the frontend code, the easiest way is to update Flinks.WebDemo/wwwroot/js/app/environments/environments.dev.ts to use another instance, such as demo. To use the localhost, just open Flinks.sln and run it (you will have two visual studio windows).